# What does "sudo su -s /bin/bash - <username>" do?

Tags: sudo

Could someone kind enough explain to me what this command means?

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash - foo
```

I was told that if I want to switch to a different account in this case "foo" without knowing its password use this command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo` is a command that executes whatever command follows as another user (if no username is given like in this case, that user is `root`) - to be able to do this, the account from which `sudo` is being executed needs to have the necessary permissions setup (see `/etc/sudoers`)

`su` starts a new shell under a different user id

`-s /bin/bash` specifies the shell to be started, i.e. `/bin/bash`

`-` makes that shell a login shell

`foo` is the user with whose user id and group id will the new shell be started

Comment: Thank you for your explanation which is very clear for me to understand!

Comment: it's also overly long.  If `sudo` is configured to let you run any command as any user, you can just use `sudo -u foo -i`